# Cocke Younger Kasami (CYK) algorithm and computer vision

Tags: parsing, nlp, context-free-grammar, cyk

You may have seen the triangular matrix for syntactic analysis. Is there any implementation of the CYK Algorithm using computer vision?

[image]

Comment: Can you explain where you see any possible application of computer vision to CYK? At least for me, it is far from obvious.

Comment: If not, I am thinking of something groundbreaking.